# Find duplicates by date interval

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the first 3 columns in the below table and I would like to obtaing the 4th one (CLASHING). If, over partition by account, the period between start and end dates is clashing, I would like to mark it as 'X'.

```
ACCOUNT     START         END   CLASHING
----------------------------------------
      1 30-Sep-21   28-Oct-21         NO
      1 01-Jul-21   20-Aug-21         NO
      2 30-Jul-21   28-Oct-21        YES
      2 01-Jul-21   20-Aug-21        YES
```

Comment: can you explain a bit better what do you mean by duplicates ? what is your input data and what select are you using to get that output ? and what output do you expect in relation with the one shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
                   FROM   table_name x
                   WHERE  x."START" < t."END"
                   AND    x."END"   > t."START"
                   AND    x.account = t.account
                   AND    x.ROWID   != t.ROWID)
       THEN 'YES'
       ELSE 'NO'
       END AS clashing
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ACCOUNT, "START", "END") AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-09-30', DATE '2021-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-07-21', DATE '2021-08-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-07-30', DATE '2021-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2021-08-20' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCOUNT | START | END | CLASHING |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 30-SEP-21 | 28-OCT-21 | NO |
> | 1 | 21-JUL-21 | 20-AUG-21 | NO |
> | 2 | 30-JUL-21 | 28-OCT-21 | YES |
> | 2 | 01-JUL-21 | 20-AUG-21 | YES |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=659b121e30a1c1394a92891a061927ee)*

Comment: It throws -01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."

Comment: @banana_99 The query I gave does not use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` and the fiddle linked at the bottom of the answer shows that it works.

Comment: @banana_99 It works on Oracle 11gR2 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=659b121e30a1c1394a92891a061927ee)

Comment: My table_name is a CTE. Is there any way to escape that ORA 01446 without to actually having to create the table first?

Comment: @banana_99 Probably, but it is impossible to answer without a [MRE] that replicates the issue. If you create a fiddle that replicates the issue then you might be able to get a solution.

Comment: Please find DB fiddle here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1859d813b45c44146bff82652e7f3939

Comment: @banana_99 That is only because you don't actually have a table there so the `ROWID` pseudo-column won't exist. You can proxy it using `ROWNUM` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0dd5ce4a72ebc5bc98bad977a0f5752d).